# SQL - Summing Null Values

Tags: t-sql, null

I am trying to SUM work hours for the year 2010 for employees using the following script. Some employees may have multiple lines in the table for the same year. Although a field will populate with 0 if there are no hours, the total result may indicate NULL. I am using a SQL Standard 2005. Suggestions would be appreciated.

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT id, year, SUM(ISNULL(Reghours_worked, 0))       AS   RegHours, SUM(ISNULL(OThours, 0)) 
  OThours, SUM(RegHours + OThours) AS TotalHours_2010
FROM         dbo.hours
WHERE     (year = '2010')
GROUP BY id, year
ORDER BY id
```

``

Results below:

```
 id Year    RegHours    OTHours Total Hours
 658261 2010    1449            0   1449
 752466 2010    1743            0   1743
 144444 2010    1750            0   1750
 652152 2010    1142            0   NULL
 926541 2010    0           0   0
```

Comment: `SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT id, year, SUM(ISNULL(Reghours_worked, 0))       AS   RegHours, SUM(ISNULL(OThours, 0)) 
  OThours, SUM(ISNULL(RegHours,0) + ISNULL(OThours,0)) AS TotalHours_2010
FROM         dbo.hours
WHERE     (year = '2010')
GROUP BY id, year Order BY id`

Comment: you don't need `sum(reghours+othours)` those values are ALREADY sums, and their values wouldn't be ready until after the row's generated. just `reghours+othous as total_hours` should do.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  TOP (100) PERCENT id, year, SUM(ISNULL(Reghours_worked, 0)) AS RegHours, 
                  SUM(ISNULL(OThours, 0)) AS OThours,  
                  SUM(ISNULL(Reghours_worked, 0)+ ISNULL(OThours, 0)) AS TotalHours_2010
FROM  dbo.hours
WHERE (year = '2010')
GROUP BY id, year
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Tip: Good information about `COALESCE` and `ISNULL` is at SQL Server Pro [here](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull) and MSDN Blogs [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for sharing this information, I would definitely check that out.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Ruchi's answer fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanx WinnieBear for trying out the solution, please make it as a answer if it worked for you :)